# Timer question: Phase Correct PWM at specific frequency

Tags: interrupt, pwm, timers, wave

I am trying to create a sinusoidal wave segmented in 64 **Frame**, each holding a **Duty cycle** precisely varying from 0x00 to 0xff. This is for an Arduino Nano.

I have trouble understanding the following:

- Which Wave Generator Mode and Matches will cause an interrupt at the constant **Frame** as well as help do a phase correct/fast PWM for the varying **Duty Cycle**?
- How to tell which pin to use? I guess OC0B means Pin5 [according to Pin Mapping](http://brittonkerin.com/cduino/pin_map.html) but I'm not sure I truly understand.

This is what I have for the moment.

```
const byte waveFrame = 126;
const byte wave[]    = {
    0x80,0x98,/*a total of 64 values*/,0x67
};
byte frame = 0;
void setup(){
    pinMode(3,OUTPUT);
    noInterrupts();
    TCCR0A = (1<< WGM00)  // Phase correct PWM with top as OCR0A
           | (1<<COM0A0)  // Toggle OC0A on match
           | (1<<COM0B1); // Clear/Set OC0B on Compare Match when up/down-counting.
    TCCR0B = (1<<  CS01); // Prescaler of 8 (16MHz/8= 2MHz)
    TCNT0  = 0;           // Counter restarted
    OCR0A  = waveFrame;   // Constant frequency/64 for each frame
    OCR0B  = 0;           // Duty Cycle
    interrupts();
}
ISR(TIMER2_COMPA_vect){
    OCR0B = wave[frame & 0x3f]; //Rolls around
    frame++;
}
```

Thank you! I've lost a little bit of hair on this.

Comment: Are you sure your attiny runs at 16Mhz? The output pin is pin  OC0B, which is pin 6 on the ATTiny45. Not sure why you are using the pin mapping of the ATMega644P. Please tell us which processor you are actually using, because mentions three.

Comment: Thanks Gerben, I removed the comment regarding the ATTiny as it was not relevant to the issue here described. I'm using the Arduino Nano's ATMega indeed.

Comment: OC0B is on arduino pin 5. It seems you code also enables output on OC0A, which is Arduino pin 6, giving you a fixed 50% percent duty cycles. Which is quite useful when you are debugging things, and have it connected to a oscilloscope, or logic analyzer . EDIT Disregard this last part if you actually want to use waveform mode 1.

Comment: You'd want Waveform Generation Mode 5. This is PWM, Phase
Correct, but with TOP being the value of OCR0A instead of 255. For mode 5 you need to set both the WGM00 and WGM02 bits. Note that the WGM02 bit is in the TCCR0B register

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> pinMode(3,OUTPUT);

Pin 3 on the Nano is `OC2B`. It's PWM is controlled by Timer 2. You
want to use pin 5 (`OC0B`), since you are using Timer 0. Or
switch to Timer 2.

> Phase correct PWM with top as OCR0A

Note that this is the description of mode 5. If you want this mode, you
have to set both the bit `WGM00` in `TCCR0A` (which you did)
and the bit `WGM02` in `TCCR0B` (which you didn't). Here you have set
mode 1: phase correct PWM with top = 0xff.

Comment: Not sure why I didn't validate it then. Thank you! That helped quite a fair bit!